# web-mode not working inside of org-mode src block

Tags: org-mode, web-mode

I am trying to write code snippets inside org-mode and I am not able to get the same effect from web-mode.

If I write the code in a css file completely I get this:
[image]

But when I write the same code inside of org-mode and put the major mode as web, I get the following: 
[image]

How can I fix this such that I get the same properties of web-mode inside of org-mode as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use either css mode:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC css
.inputField {
   color: #525252;
}
#+END_SRC
```

and add color fontification by using code found [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_CSS_colors.html),

or inline the css in web:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC web
<style>
.inputField {
   color: #525252;
}
</style>
#+END_SRC
```

**EDIT** after comment from @predicate and @Dan:

Ok, I see. The problem is, that `web-mode` detects css based on file extension, which does not work for source blocks. As a workaround you could define a minimal helper mode for each language you use. You would have to call `web-mode` to initialize web mode and then change the type by setting buffer local variable `web-mode-content-type` to `"css"`, `"javascript"`, `"json"` or `"jsx"`.

Here an example for a web-css-mode:

```el
(define-derived-mode web-css-mode web-mode "WebCss"
  "Major mode for editing web css templates."
  (web-mode)
  (setq web-mode-content-type "css"))
```

And its usage in org-mode:

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC web-css
.inputField {
   color: #525252;
   color: #dfdfdf;
   color: #FFCC02;
   color: #FFE477;
}
#+END_SRC
```

**Bonus**:

Did not try it, but you might also be able to define another engine by inserting

`/* -*- engine:php -*- */`

(replacing php with the engine you want, see variable `web-mode-engines` or topic "Associate an engine" [here](http://web-mode.org/)) in your buffer.

Comment: I use web-mode for writing a lot of different languages other than css,
this solutions will work for only css.